# How to change input language in adobe air'

Tags: apache-flex, input, air, adobe

I want change the default operation system language from inside adobe air programmatic, keep getting English, event if current lang is something else and air application is loaded.

Thanks///

Comment: What have you tried?  I think you'll need a NativeProcess or NativeExtension to do this; as I doubt AIR exposes that functionality.

Comment: I don't get it? isn't it possible to change the keyboard language from withing air application??

Comment: I doubt it; unless you use a NativeProcess or NativeExtension.  What makes you think this should be Native AIR functionality?  From my view; changing Operating Systems settings, such as the default language, is not a standard use case for most users. Why would Adobe take care to expose this functionality via AIR APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The Application-class has a style-property called "locale".

You can change this by using

```
this.setStyle("locale", "de_DE");
```

for changing it at runtime. Or check your compiler-settings. Flash Builder sets locale to en_US by default.

Comment: this is set my locales (strings and currency etc), I want to change the keyboard input language

Comment: The keyboard layout? Okay, then Rebook711 is correct, you need a nativeprocess